# Azure Bicep script produces error "Changing property > 'agentPoolProfile.vnetSubnetID' is not allowed." on second execution

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-aks, azure-bicep

I'm using Azure Bicep to create a virtualNetwork with a single subnet and then use that as the input for creating an aks cluster with : `vnetSubnetID: virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[0].id`

The first time I run the command, it creates the virtual network and cluster just fine, but the second time I run the command it gives this error :

> {"error":{"code":"InvalidTemplateDeployment","message":"The template
> deployment 'cluster' is not valid according to the validation
> procedure. The tracking id is '[REDACTED_JUST_IN_CASE]'. See inner errors for
> details.","details":[{"code":"PropertyChangeNotAllowed","message":"Provisioning
> of resource(s) for container service playground-cluster0 in resource
> group showcase-kevinplayground2 failed. Message: {\n  "code":
> "PropertyChangeNotAllowed",\n  "message": "Changing property
> 'agentPoolProfile.vnetSubnetID' is not allowed.",\n  "target":
> "agentPoolProfile.vnetSubnetID"\n }. Details: "}]}}

I double checked and there is just the one subnet inside the virtualNetwork created by the deployment (no other magically appeared or anything).

I repeated the experiment on a second resource group and the same thing happened, so it's reproducible.

Here is the full bicep file (just call `az deployment group create --resource-group showcase-kevinplayground2 -f cluster.bicep` in the resource group of your choice)

```
targetScope = 'resourceGroup'
resource virtualNetwork 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'aksVirtualNetwork'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  properties:{
    addressSpace:{
      addressPrefixes:[
        '10.10.0.0/16'
      ]
    }
    subnets:[
      {
        name: 'aks'
        properties:{
          addressPrefix: '10.10.5.0/24'
        }
      }
    ]
    
  }
}

resource aksManagedIdentity 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' = {
  name: 'playgroundIdentity'
  location: resourceGroup().location
}

resource aks 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters@2021-02-01' = {
  name: 'playground-cluster0'
  location: resourceGroup().location
  identity: {
    type:'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${aksManagedIdentity.id}': {}
    }
  }
  sku: {
    name: 'Basic'
    tier: 'Free'
  }
  properties: {
    kubernetesVersion: '1.21.2'
    dnsPrefix: 'playground'
    enableRBAC: true

    networkProfile: {
      networkPlugin: 'azure'
      networkPolicy: 'calico'
    }

    aadProfile: {
      managed: true
      enableAzureRBAC: true
    }

    autoUpgradeProfile: {}

    apiServerAccessProfile: {
      enablePrivateCluster: false
    }
    
    agentPoolProfiles: [
      {
        name: 'aksnodes'
        count: 1
        vmSize: 'Standard_B2s'
        osDiskSizeGB: 30
        osDiskType: 'Managed'
        vnetSubnetID: virtualNetwork.properties.subnets[0].id
        osType: 'Linux'
        maxCount: 1
        minCount: 1
        enableAutoScaling: true
        type: 'VirtualMachineScaleSets'
        mode: 'System'
        orchestratorVersion: null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this reported [github issue](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/695), you need to use the `resourceId` function.
In your case, something like that should work:

```
vnetSubnetID: resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets', 'aksVirtualNetwork', 'aks')
```

Comment: The docs says : "The resourceId function is available in Bicep files, but typically you don't need it. Instead, use the symbolic name for the resource and access the id property."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/bicep-functions-resource#resourceid

But for some reason, you are right and it fixed the issue! I'm curious as to why the symbolic name resolution didn't work in this case...

Comment: I think because you use an array indexer `subnets[0].id`. Guessing when the validation happens it s before the the `subnets[0].id` is resolved and it just failed saying that you're trying to change this property. Something like that